# String as input in function - Python

Tags: python, string, function

I'm trying to make a function which do this :

```
k="a"+"q"
print k
```

Output: `aq`

So, to define my function, I'm doing this :

```
def con(p):
 print "a" + "p"
```

I test my funcion: `con(i)`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-ed8318952c9a> in <module>()
      2  print "a" + "p"
      3 
----> 4 con(i)
      5 

NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

My expected output is ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a colon

```
def con(p):
```

1. If you are passing a string as a parameter, it should be passed with single or double quotes surrounding that.
2. If you are accessing the parameter, you don't need the quotes around them.

So, your program should look like this

```
def con(p):
    print "a" + p

con("i")
```

Comment: I forgot it, but it didn't work well anymay, check mi edited post.

Comment: With that definition the output is ap for any text string

Comment: @CreamStat Nope. If you do `con("a")`, output will be `"aa"`

Comment: I use Ipython and the result is still ap for that case.

Comment: @CreamStat Are you sure `print` line doesn't have quotes around `p`?

Comment: I don't know why some minutes ago the function gave strange results with the same code, now your code is working OK, Thanks!